# hook_node_presave() fired twice when adding new node

Tags: 7, hooks, entities

I've just noticed that `hook_node_presave($node)` is fired twice when adding new nodes: Once it's called from `node_form_submit()`; the second time from `entity_save()`.
It turns out that `$node->nid` is not set in first call, but it is already present in the second one.

Is this a normal behavior for `hook_node_presave($node)` in Drupal 7? Does the node containing node reference fields make a difference?

Comment: It should only be invoked from node_save(), field_attach_presave() and user_save() *(I have no idea what for in the last case)*. How exactly did you test it? What is stack trace of these calls you describe?

Comment: You can use [`ddebug_backtrace`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/ddebug_backtrace/7.x-1.x) to see why the `hook_node_presave` is triggered twice. As @Mołot mentioned, Drupal 7 core only trigger it twice. It may happen by some contrib / custom module.